# Check Flask cookie for user_id and obtain User if it exists or redirect if not

Tags: python, flask

What I'm after is something like what the @login_required decorators accomplish but I'm not sure if a custom decorator would allow me to pass the User option back to my route function. There are several pages in my app that require the user to be logged in to access them so I am looking for the most efficient way/least code to copy into each access-restricted route that will verify they have a user_id in their cookie (logged in), cache get/query for their User object using the user_id, and carry on with the route function, else redirect to the login page if user_id is not present.

What I was hoping to do was something like:

```
@noteBP.route('/note', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_note():

user_details = return_user_details_if_logged_in_else_redirect_to_login_url(next=request.url)
...
```

And that function would check for the user_id in the session cookie and send back the User object or redirect to the login page:

```
def return_user_details_if_logged_in_else_redirect_to_login_url(next=None):
  user_id = session.get('user_id')
  if user_id:
    user_details = user_util.get_user_details_by_id(user_id)
    return user_details
  else:
    return redirect(url_for('usersBP.login', next=next))
```

Turns out, redirect does not work the same way as Abort where it gets called even if you are inside another function so now I have do do additional processing back in the route function to check:

```
user_details = return_user_details_if_logged_in_else_redirect_to_login_url(next=request.url)
if not user_details:
      return redirect(redirect_url)
```

I'm looking to avoid having to paste this chunk of code at the top of every access-restricted route. Is there a more efficient way/DRY approach to do this? if with a decorator, how do I get the user_details into the route function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect in a function called inside a view, raise a `RequestRedirect`. If you want to redirect in a decorator, check if the user is not logged in and return a redirect rather than the actual view (or use the previous function to raise the redirect).

```
import functools
from flask import url_for, redirect, g
from werkzeug.routing import RequestRedirect

def require_login():
    if g.user is None:
        raise RequestRedirect(url_for('login'))

def login_required(view):
    @functools.wraps(view)
    def wrapped_view(**kwargs):
        require_login()

        # or
        # if g.user is None:
        #     return redirect(url_for('login'))

        return view(**kwargs)

    return wrapped_view

@app.route('/secret2')
@login_required
def secret1():
    return 'secret 1'

@app.route('/secret2')
def secret2():
    require_login()
    return 'secret 2'
```

Populate `g.user` in a `before_request` handler.

```
from flask import session

@app.before_request
def load_user():
    g.user = None

    if 'user_id' in session:
        # use whatever caching logic you want here.
        g.user = User.query.get(session['user_id'])
```

Populate `session['user_id']` in your login view.

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=request.form['username']).first()

        if user and user.check_password(request.form['password']:
            session['user_id'] = user.id
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('login.html')
```

Now you can access `g.user` from any route, without passing it explicitly. If you do want to pass it explicitly, modify `login_required`.

```
def require_login():
    if g.user is None:
        raise RequestRedirect(url_for('login'))

    return g.user

def login_required(view):
    @functools.wraps
    def wrapped_view(**kwargs):
        user = require_login()
        return view(user, **kwargs)

    return wrapped_view

@app.route('/secret')
def secret(user):
    return 'user {} is logged in'.format(user.id)
```

Give that all of this except passing the user is part of Flask-Login, you should really reconsider using Flask-Login instead of trying to maintain your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is a function that wraps and replaces another function. Since the original function is replaced, you need to remember to copy the original function’s information to the new function. Use [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to handle this for you.

This example assumes that the login page is called `'login'` and that the *current user* is stored in `g.user` and is `None` if there is no-one logged in.

```py
from functools import wraps
from flask import g, request, redirect, url_for

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if g.user is None:
            return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

To use the decorator, apply it as innermost decorator to a view function. When applying further decorators, always remember that the [**`route()`**](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.route) decorator is the outermost.

```py
@app.route('/secret_page')
@login_required
def secret_page():
    pass
```

#### Note:

The `next` value will exist in `request.args` after a `GET` request for the login page. You’ll have to pass it along when sending the `POST` request from the login form. You can do this with a hidden input tag, then retrieve it from `request.form` when logging the user in.

```html
<input type="hidden" value="{{ request.args.get('next', '') }}"/>
```